# Preventing javascript to redirect the page after sending the form

Tags: javascript

Hell
I have a form on my page that I submit it using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
```

But this command redirects the page to the form action's page. and I don't want this to happen and stay on the page.

Please help me to solve this problem

(also I've googled it up but there were no useful information)

Comment: Where is the page submitting?  Do you want it to submit to the serverside?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i thinks this is duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102902/using-preventdefault-on-a-submit-button

Comment: Use this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting sends you to the URL specified in the ACTION of the form via POST. This is not a redirect.

If you want to stay on the same page, use AJAX techniques, or post the form for a hidden Iframe.

Comment: i can send forms without redirecting when im using a submit button instead of javascript. i this it should be possiblle

Comment: Once again, submitting a form does not redirect in the first place.